# How do I enable the Crowd Rest API? ('Not enabled: Crowd REST API' exception thrown)

Tags: jira, confluence, atlassian-crowd

I'm trying to install Atlassian's Crowd product (v2.4) and once the initial install completes, I keep getting a fatal exception with:

Description : Required plugins failed to initialise. Please check the logs for errors and restart Crowd.
Message: Not enabled: Crowd REST API.

How do I enable the Crowd Rest API, or get past this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Message here is somewhat misleading.

What's actually happening (or at least, it was in my case), is that I was trying to use a version of the JDK that isn't yet supported by Crowd.

I had tried getting through the install numerous times using JDK 1.7 (latest) and Crowd 2.4 (latest). It all looked like it was working perfectly, until the initial service stopped running, at which point I'd be blocked by the message quoted above.

**The solution ultimately turned out to be downgrading to JDK 1.6.** As soon as I did this, I was able to get past the error and Crowd worked exactly as expected (I could fully integrate with JIRA and Confluence). According to the Atlassian support forum, downgrading to Crowd 2.3 is also a solution.

Realistically, this makes sense because the 1.7 JDK isn't listed on the [Crowd Supported Platforms](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CROWD/Supported+Platforms) page, but was something that I just didn't catch when I was configuring my environment.

Also, it took me a while to find it, but Atlassian has their own Stack Exchange site for [support questions and problems](https://answers.atlassian.com/).